# Showing non www on Google but redirecting it to www

Tags: google-search-console

In Google Webmaster Central, I have decided that my search results will be shown as non-www but I also decided that my site redirects to www. Will this be a problem for my seo.

Comment: FYI, that's not a good thing for usability as users will see one URL in Google's search results and another on your website. Consistency is a good thing. I would say pick one or the other and use it everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no. there is no problem SEO-wise. in the WMT you can set which url will be displayed (in your case: the non-www url).

just make sure to handle redirects the appropriate way. via .htacces you would need to set up the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoururl.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yoururl.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

this will redirect all incoming traffic from "yoururl.com" to "www.yoururl.com".

Answer (score 0):

foo.bar and www.foo.bar would show as separate sites if not done properly.  are you handling the redirect through a DNS cname or a 301 redirect?